# Not able to execute java utils.MulticastTest in Weblogic 11G

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I know this is very basic but i am frustrated like anything.. i googled and tried everything i could. But i am not able to execute this utility.

```
java utils.MulticastTest
```

I am using weblogic 11g on Linux open SUSE. i gotta find it soon as need to replicate on production :

Also i guess (not sure) this utility exists in weblogic.jar i am executing

```
**linux-0m8r:/bea/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/server/bin # ./setWLSEnv.sh** 
CLASSPATH=/bea/Oracle/Middleware/patch_wls1032/profiles/default/sys_manifest_classpath/weblogic_patch.jar:/bea/Oracle/Middleware/patch_oepe1032/profiles/default/sys_manifest_classpath/weblogic_patch.jar:/bea/Oracle/Middleware/jrockit_160_14_R27.6.5-32/lib/tools.jar:/bea/Oracle/Middleware/utils/config/10.3/config-launch.jar:/bea/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/weblogic_sp.jar:/bea/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/weblogic.jar:/bea/Oracle/Middleware/modules/features/weblogic.server.modules_10.3.2.0.jar:/bea/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/webservices.jar:/bea/Oracle/Middleware/modules/org.apache.ant_1.7.0/lib/ant-all.jar:/bea/Oracle/Middleware/modules/net.sf.antcontrib_1.0.0.0_1-0b2/lib/ant-contrib.jar:

PATH=/bea/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/server/bin:/bea/Oracle/Middleware/modules/org.apache.ant_1.7.0/bin:/bea/Oracle/Middleware/jrockit_160_14_R27.6.5-32/jre/bin:/bea/Oracle/Middleware/jrockit_160_14_R27.6.5-32/bin:/home/tty/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/games

Your environment has been set.
```

even after that when i run

```
$ java utils.MulticastTest -N server100 -A 237.155.155.1
```

it gives following error:

```
linux-0m8r:/bea/Oracle/Middleware/jdk160_14_R27.6.5-32/bin # ./java utils.MulticastTest -N server100 -A 237.155.155.1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: utils/MulticastTest
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: utils.MulticastTest
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
Could not find the main class: utils.MulticastTest.  Program will exit.
```

Also i have two jdk installed first is OS one and one bundled with weblogic.  tried with both but not able to run it.. it is purely an classpath issue i can see but i am unable to figure it out how to solve it .. any help will be highly appreciated .. i am availabe for next 12 hours for any questions ..

```
linux-0m8r:/bea/Oracle/Middleware/jdk160_14_R27.6.5-32/bin # java -version
java version "1.6.0_17"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.7.3) (suse-7.3-i386)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 14.0-b16, mixed mode)


linux-0m8r:/bea/Oracle/Middleware/jdk160_14_R27.6.5-32/bin # ./java -version
java version "1.6.0_14"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_14-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 14.0-b16, mixed mode)
linux-0m8r:/bea/Oracle/Middleware/jdk160_14_R27.6.5-32/bin #
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your environment is actually NOT set. You need to *source* the script using either [`source`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internal.html#SOURCEREF) or `.` (the "[dot](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html#DOTREF)" command):

```
$ cd Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/server/bin
$ . ./setWLSEnv.sh
CLASSPATH=...

PATH=...

Your environment has been set.
$ java utils.MulticastTest -n name -a address [-p portnumber] [-t timeout] [-s send] [-l timetolive]
```

Comment: yeah thanks man that worked that time ...   was newbie that time :)